# Using Python's sympy module to express a complicated function

Tags: python, sympy

How can I symbolically express the following equation using python's sympy module, such that I could later find the second derivative and therefore compute the Hessian matrix?

The Function

[image]

What I've tried:

```
import sympy
Nc,Ns,Tc,Ysc,theta,theta_star,t,dt,sigma_s,measured,simulated=sympy.symbols(' Nc Ns Tc Ysc theta theta_star t dt sigma_s  measured simulated ')
chi=(1/2*Nc*Ns) * sympy.mpmath.nsum(   1 / Tc *  sympy.integrate(  ((simulated - measured)  /  sigma_s )    **2) , (t,0,Tc))
```

The Error:

```
  File "C:\Anaconda1\lib\site-packages\sympy\concrete\expr_with_limits.py", line 358, in __new__
    "specify dummy variables for %s" % function)

ValueError: specify dummy variables for (-measured + simulated)**2/sigma_s**2
```

Comment: BTW your expression starting `chi=(1/2*Nc*Ns)` if it should be the same as the equation above should be written as either `chi=(1/2/Nc/Ns)` or `chi=(1/(2*Nc*Ns))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `sympy.mpmath.nsum`. mpmath functions are for numerical calculations only. Do represent a sum symbolically, use `sympy.Sum`. It works like this

```
In [3]: Sum(f(x), (x, 0, n))
Out[3]:
  n
 ___
 ╲
  ╲   f(x)
  ╱
 ╱
 ‾‾‾
x = 0
```

Secondly, SymPy has to be told explicitly when one variable depends on another. I'm unclear what `s` and `c` are in your equation. If they are variables, then you should create symbols `s` and `c`. Importantly, `t` needs to be a variable, and things that depend on `t` need to be functions like

```
thetastar, t = symbols('thetastar t')
y_sc = Function('y')
```

and then use

```
y_sc(thetastar, t)
```

(if `s` and `c` are supposed to be variables as well, then you should use `y = Function('y')` and `y(s, c, thetastar, t)`).

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you are telling it to integrate with the integration variable of t, but the function `((simulated - measured)  /  sigma_s ) **2` doesn't have t as a variable.